# Hosting a website from my VM (Local private network)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, webserver, localhost

I am hosting a website in my `virtualbox` (vm). Host is windows 10 and guest is ubuntu.

Vm have two network adapter:

Adapter-1 = `Host-only-adapter` (ip:192.68.88.10/24)

Adapter-2 = `Bridge-adapter`(From drop down selected my computer `physical adapter`)

**My computer connected to 10 computers with a `switch`. How can they browse my website?**

> **I already try this:**
>   Install Mikrotik router OS on another VM and route `Adapter-1` traffic to physical Adapter of my pc but fail to access website in networking.

Any solution on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the IP address that is associated with the Bridged network on the VM.  If you have DNS for your LAN then you can create an A record pointing to that IP as well.

Comment: How create DNS for LAN or any article? Thanks